# How I can do Elastic Search nested query with java api, QueryBuilder

Tags: java, spring, elasticsearch

Here is the object cuptured with kibana, which should be returned with java api

```
{
  "_index": "backend:nips-000320",
  "_type": "_doc",
  "_id": "qhcOVoQBFSMoMXEJjh46",
  "_version": 1,
  "_score": 0,
  "_source": {
    "severity": 5,
    "priority": 37,
    "@geo": {
      "Source": {
        "Continent": {
          "Code": "EU",
          "GeoNameID": 6255148,
          "Name": "Europe"
        },
        "Country": {
          "IsInEuropeanUnion": false,
          "IsoCode": "UA",
          "GeoNameID": 690791,
          "Name": "Ukraine"
        }
      }
    },
    "timestamp": "2022-11-08T07:04:52Z"
  },
  "fields": {}
}
```

The problem is that I can't find a way to do this kind of nested query with java code and get this:

```
"@geo"."Source"."Country"."IsoCode" grouped by the value of "IsoCode".
```

like this :

```
[\{"iso_code": "US", "count": 15}, \{"iso_code": "AE", "count": 102}, {}...]
```

I am trying with QueryBuilder api, but no results yet. Any ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: @geo is field type nested? show me your java code.

Comment: as elastic returns everything in "_source" object, so it turns out that geo is not nested, but what are inside geo, those are nested,  "@geo"."Source"."Country"."IsoCode"

Comment: @rabbitbr related to showing you java code, I haven't yet found a solutuion for this, but have another queries which work well but return the whole object graph, and are extremely slow, because as mentioned, return the whole object graph list.

Comment: If you are working with nested type you can use source to return the fields you want and add inner_hits to get only the object where the match was found because that way you won't get the whole array.

Comment: @rabbitbr can you show me an example of adding inner_hits?

Comment: Yes, provide the mapping and documents please.

Comment: @rabbitbr what do you mean mapping, or documents? I have posted the data, which should be returned with the help of java api. and at the end we should have this picture et the end,

[\{"iso_code": "US", "count": 15}, \{"iso_code": "AE", "count": 102}, {}...] 

 so it turns out this nested field should be queried:

 "@geo.Source.Country.IsoCode", so the isoCode should be returned, grouped by the count of each value.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/249449/discussion-between-rabbitbr-and-hayk-mkhitaryan).